# The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request. Getting error only on other servers

Tags: c#, web-services, asp.net-web-api, httpwebrequest

There are many answers available for this question throughout the internet but my issue is different.

I am making an API call which runs successfully if I run it on local machine. My code is also in the same machine.
The issue happens only when I deploy the application and run it from different server.

I am getting the exception on `request.GetResponse()`

Following is my code

```
HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(requestUrl) as HttpWebRequest;
response = request.GetResponse(); // This throws error
```

I understand this happens when the request URL is incorrect or any parameter is missing. But if it runs fine locally, then what should be the issue behind this not running on other server.

Please help

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer.

I am posting the answer in case it may help others.
The API which I am calling required the signature which is generated each time the API is called. This signature internally gets the consumer key which I was hardcoading in my code and its different on server. so while making requestURL, it was generating invalid URL. I corrected this and now its working on server as well.